# Why does unittest.mock fail when the production class constructor takes extra arguments?

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I have run into a problem which I think might be a bug with the libraries I am using. However, I am fairly new to python, unittest, and unittest.mock libraries so this may just be a hole in my understanding.

While adding tests to some production code I have run into an error, I have produced a minimal sample that reproduces the issue:

```py
import unittest
import mock

class noCtorArg:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def okFunc(self):
        raise NotImplemented


class withCtorArg:
    def __init__(self,obj):
        pass
    def notOkFunc(self):
        raise NotImplemented
    def okWithArgFunc(self, anArgForMe):
        raise NotImplemented

class BasicTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    """Basic test Cases."""

    # passes
    def test_noCtorArg_okFunc(self):
        mockSUT = mock.MagicMock(spec=noCtorArg)
        mockSUT.okFunc()
        mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.okFunc()])

    # passes
    def test_withCtorArg_okWithArgFuncTest(self):
        mockSUT = mock.MagicMock(spec=withCtorArg)
        mockSUT.okWithArgFunc("testing")
        mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.okWithArgFunc("testing")])

    # fails
    def test_withCtorArg_doNotOkFuncTest(self):
        mockSUT = mock.MagicMock(spec=withCtorArg)
        mockSUT.notOkFunc()
        mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.notOkFunc()])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

How I run the tests and the output is as follows:

```
E:\work>python -m unittest testCopyFuncWithMock
.F.
======================================================================
FAIL: test_withCtorArg_doNotOkFuncTest (testCopyFuncWithMock.BasicTestSuite)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testCopyFuncWithMock.py", line 38, in test_withCtorArg_doNotOkFuncTest
    mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.notOkFunc()])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\mock\mock.py", line 969, in assert_has_calls
    ), cause)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 718, in raise_from
    raise value
AssertionError: Calls not found.
Expected: [call.notOkFunc()]
Actual: [call.notOkFunc()]

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.004s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

I am using python 2.7.11, with mock version 2.0.0 installed via pip.

Any suggestions for what I am doing wrong? Or does this look like a bug in the library?

Comment: Not too sure about your specific issue, but just a Python coding note - for Python2.7 classes, you always want to inherit from `object`, i.e. `class WithCtorArg(object):`. Also, class names typically start with a capital letter (though I realize that may've just gotten lost in translation to your MCVE).

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, the way you chose to perform the assert has masked your issue.

Try, instead of this:

```
mockSUT.assert_has_calls(calls=[mock.call.notOkFunc()])
```

to do this:

```
mockSUT.assert_has_calls(calls=[mock.call.notOkFunc()], any_order=True)
```

You'll see the actual exception:

```
TypeError("'obj' parameter lacking default value")
```

This is because you tried to instantiate an instance of the class `withCtorArg` that has the parameter `obj` with no default value. If you had tried to actually instantiate it directly, you would've seen:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

However, since you let the `mock` library handle the instantiation of a mock object, the error happens there - and you get the `TypeError` exception.

Modifying the relevant class:

```
class withCtorArg:
    def __init__(self, obj = None):
        pass
    def notOkFunc(self):
        pass
    def okWithArgFunc(self, anArgForMe):
        pass
```

and adding a default None value for obj solves the issue.

Comment: Yes, good point. I would have hoped that by using a mock you wouldn't need to call the actual constructor, since it's irrelevant to the SUT. Unfortunately in a real world example (at least in mine) modifying the class being mocked is not a good idea, the constructor arguments are there for a reason and are not optional, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can explain definitively why this is the case, I still suspect a bug in the Mock library, since the issue only occurs for a test case with no arguments on the called function. Thanks to advance512 for pointing out that the real error was hidden!

However to work around this issue, without having to modify the production code I am going to use the following approach:

```
# passes
@mock.patch ('mymodule.noCtorArg')
def test_noCtorArg_okFunc(self, noCtorArgMock):
    mockSUT = noCtorArg.return_value
    mockSUT.okFunc()
    mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.okFunc()])

# passes
@mock.patch ('mymodule.withCtorArg')
def test_withCtorArg_okWithArgFuncTest(self, withCtorArgMock):
    mockSUT = withCtorArg.return_value
    mockSUT.okWithArgFunc("testing")
    mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.okWithArgFunc("testing")])

# now passes
@mock.patch ('mymodule.withCtorArg')
def test_withCtorArg_doNotOkFuncTest(self, withCtorArgMock):
    mockSUT = withCtorArg.return_value
    mockSUT.notOkFunc()
    mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.notOkFunc()], any_order=True)
```

**Edit:**

One problem with this is that the mock does not have `spec` set. This means that the SUT is able to call methods that do not exist on the original class definition.

An alternative approach is to wrap the class to be mocked:

```
class withCtorArg:
    def __init__(self,obj):
        pass
    def notOkFunc(self):
        raise NotImplemented
    def okWithArgFunc(self, anArgForMe):
        raise NotImplemented

class wrapped_withCtorArg(withCtorArg):
    def __init__(self):
        super(None)

class BasicTestSuite(unittest.TestCase):
    """Basic test Cases."""

    # now passes
    def test_withCtorArg_doNotOkFuncTest(self):
        mockSUT = mock.MagicMock(spec=wrapped_withCtorArg)
        mockSUT.notOkFunc()
        #mockSUT.doesntExist() #causes the test to fail. "Mock object has no attribute 'doesntExist'"
        assert isinstance (mockSUT, withCtorArg)
        mockSUT.assert_has_calls([mock.call.notOkFunc()], any_order=True)
```

Comment: Trying to instantiate an instance of a class that has required parameters in its constructor, without giving it arguments, would fail if you had tried to do it directly. Why do you expect it to work in a mock, especially a MagicMock that automatically "wraps" various methods and monitors the calls you made and if they're valid or not? :) I'd say that the behaviour you saw makes sense, except for the bug in the library.

Comment: I hoped that the library would wrap the constructor (like I have done in this answer), since we don't _really_ want an instance of the class. We only want a pretend one that actually doesn't do anything except spy on the calls made, and fake return values. In this case we don't really even care that the constructor signature matches since it is going to be created outside the SUT and injected.

Comment: Alternatively, it would be fine if there was a way to supply the constructor parameters when creating a mock so they can be forwarded to the class constructor. Do you know how to do that with this mock library? I haven't found anything in the documentation about creating mocks for classes with constructor arguments at all. Thanks for your interest by the way.

Comment: Remember that mock objects and classes are usually meant to be used instead of the real objects, so it makes sense they're require the same type of parameters for instantiation, since the constructor is yet another function to monitor. As for the ctor question, you can try calling mockSUT.__init__(params) directly, though I'm certain there's a better way to do it.